# Open background tab in mobile browser leads to: "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script ..."

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, vite

I have created a web application with vite and react and I occasionally encounter the following error when I leave the browser tab open, change the app e.g. from Edge or Chrome to some other app and come back later (does not matter if it is a few minutes or hours):

```
Failed to load module script: 
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

The problem is, that I am unable to recreate the error reliably, and I do not know how to solve it.

This happens only in the mobile browser (edge, chrome, Firefox) on android and I have never encountered it in a desktop browser.

A simple refresh or reload of the browser tab is enough to make it work again, but this not the best possible user experience, so it should work directly if one reopens the browser tab. And usually, it does (as I said, unfortunately I am unable to recreate this behavior reliably).

I observed this behavior for a few weeks now, and I am out of ideas, and I hope someone can give me a hint.

Any help is very much appreciated.

The application in question can be found here: [capmon.org](https://capmon.org). It is not relevant on which page you navigate. As far as I am aware, it does happen on every page in the application.

I am uncertain if it is helpful to solve the problem, but here is the index.html of the React/vite application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
        />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />

        <title>CapMon</title>

        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <!-- <body> -->
    <body class="myContainer">
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/index.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```